# from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService is not working

Tags: python-3.x, azure, pip

Since the past few weeks, I was able to access azure storage through python packages and create blobs and upload csvs into a container.
Today, when I tried to upload a bulk of csvs into a blob, I got an error.

Apparently, when I run `from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess` - I get the error - ImportError: cannot import name 'BlockBlobService' from 'azure.storage.blob' (unknown location)

I have shared the packages that are installed on my machine.

What am I doing wrong?
Since I'm still new to python, if anyone could explain to me in a simple manner, the libraries I need to install (and how), that would be nice.
Thanks!

I apologize I'm not able to upload the list of packages that I have for Azure. 
What I did was `pip install azure` followed by `pip install azure.storage.blob`

Comment: which version of the python package are you running? there is a new preview version of that package where BlockBlobService does not exist anymore. Maybe you switched your version at some point? https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/ (version 12 is the new one)

Comment: azure==4.0.0, azure-storage-blob==1.5.0, azure-storage-common==1.4.2, azure-storage-file==1.4.0, azure-storage-queue==1.4.0  
This is what I have. Are you suggesting I uninstall everything and simply install the azure package?

Answer (score 7):

I believe you were following the new guide which uses `azure-storage-blob` and were trying to use code for the old `azure-storage` library, thus the `ImportError`.

Since `BlockBlobService` is from the old `azure-storage` library, to continue using it, you need to `pip uninstall azure-storage-blob` if you have installed the new library by accident, and then `pip install azure-storage` to install the old library.

If you would like to use the new library or cannot do the above, feel free to refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58900508/5305519) which details the context and full instructions of using either the new `azure-storage-blob` library or the old `azure-storage` library.